# SSH не видит команду

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, shell, ssh

Всем привет. Первый раз тут, потому что столкнулся действительно со сложной проблемой.Начнем по порядку. Имеется кластерная система, главный узел и остальные ноды, все они связаны по ssh,везде настроен беспарольный доступ. На главном узле имеется своя специальная шеловская команда(epk) для запуска нужной задачи. Происходит это так "epk -f example.conf -p example.ini". Это специальные входные файлы, в которых указан путь до задачи,которую нужно выполнять, пути куда записывать логи и тд. После запуска этой команды в терминале выводится сообщение "epk start" и затем терминал становится в режим ожидания, ничего нельзя ввести, до тех пор пока задача не закончит выполняться. Мне необходимо было написать сайт для такой кластерной системы. Сайт лежит на отдельной машине, там сервер апач, пхп, и он связан с главным узлом по ssh. Все как положено. Необходимо теперь написать пхп скрипт,который при нажатии на кнопку передает команду главному узлу "epk -f example.conf -p example.ini", то есть там должна запускаться задача. Я пробовал через ssh2_exec не получается, пробовал так exec('ssh user@192.168.14.14 epk -f example.conf -p example.ini') и тоже не получается, просто задача не запускается пхп скрипт должен был по идеи встать на ожидание, до тех пор, пока ему эта команда не вернет результат. А тут вообще ноль реакции. Я попробовал сделать вручную, зашел на сервер,где лежит сайт, запустил терминал и ввел команду ssh user@192.168.14.14 epk -f example.conf -p example.ini, на что получил ответ, что epk не найден. Но когда я сначала подключаюсь по ssh, а только потом пишу epk -f example.conf -p example.ini, то все работает. **Есть идеи как решить мою проблему?** Уже все форумы облазял.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Скорее всего при прямом запуске не обрабатывается *.profile* на стороне сервера, потому и не видит вашей команды. Указывайте полные пути.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать симлинк в `/usr/bin/`: `sudo ln -sf /путь/к/epk /usr/bin/epk`